# Paste text into textarea from clipboard when moveover using javaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to paste data from clipboard to textarea

```
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea',
        plugins: "paste",
        paste_data_images: true
    });

    function handlePaste (e) {
        var clipboardData, pastedData;

        // Stop data actually being pasted into div
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get pasted data via clipboard API
        clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

        // Do whatever with pasteddata
        var paste = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
        paste.innerText = pastedData;
    }

    document.getElementById('mytextarea').addEventListener('mouseenter', handlePaste);
</script>
```

But nothing happening no error. I found many answers but i none solved my problem

Comment: What web browser are you using?

Comment: If you inspect the DOM after applying tinymce to your `#mytextarea` selector, it may well be that the text area no longer exists or has been replaced by tinymce DOM elements.  You may need to apply your event listener to those DOM elements rather than the one you passed to tinymce.

Comment: chrome@NickParsons

Comment: i did asu said @snapjs
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " data-id="mytextarea" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p></body>

Answer (score 3):

I believe in Chrome you can only access clipboardData when handling the `paste` event. So you would have to be listening for that event to access the clipboardData.

Change your event listener to listen for the `paste` event, and then you can do whatever you want with the clipboardData in the handler:

`document.getElementById('mytextarea').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);`

You can see this in action in the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/x3v8bhhr/

I added a second `textarea`. When you try to paste into the first `textarea`, the clipboardData is intercepted, and placed in the second `textarea` instead.